# Android Gradle Release build libraries

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-build, build.gradle

In my Android Studio project I have 2 flavours both having separate corresponding dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    libflavour1Compile project(':TestLib1')
    libflavour2Compile project(':TestLib2')
}
```

Building both of these flavours in debug works great, pulling in their respectful resources.

However, for both flavours debug and release urls are needed.  To 'TestLib1' I added strings.xml to the release/res/values folder.  Now the build is always inserting this release string to the debug build.

In Android Studio, selecting all build variants to be Debug still results in the release string being used even though the folder is not highlighted.

[image]

Creating a Debug build on the command line also has the same result.

```
./gradlew installLibflavour1Debug
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here or do libraries always default to the Release build type?

Comment: There's nothing wrong. When a project uses a library, it uses the release version - even when you choose debug for the project.

Comment: Thanks @Marcelo, I found this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/lyeeJTEGyhQ/wNAICMsOkiUJ)  discussing the same idea